# How to build a specialized installer in VS2010?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, iis, installation, windows-installer

I'm looking to build a specialized msi installer, preferably with VS2010 to do the following:

1. Be able to configure SQL server connection.
2. Pick the database to be used from the SQl server.
3. Create database table with specified credentials.
4. Assign a new DB user a set of permissions.
5. Also configure the IIS application.

I looked into a default installer project in VS2010 and it has nothing related to dealing with SQL server and IIS. Any idea how can I do all this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Studio setup projects do not offer support for SQL scripts and IIS. The best you can do is write some custom actions (using custom code) to handle this during install.

Commercial setup authoring tools offer the most control over SQL scripts and IIS elements. You can find a list here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software

You can also try [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/). It has a steep learning curve, but it's free and gets the job done.

Comment: Wix ;) Makes all you need, is fee and the learning curve is NOT steep - if you make .net installers you better kjnow what you do. There are ton of crappy ones around.